# Unable to insert into mySQL database using python, variables and auto_increment

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, mysql-python

I hope my formatting is OK as this is my first time using stackOverflow

No matter how I change my code and methods I keep on getting the same bug when executing this code

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py",
>   line 83, in **call**
>       return bytes(self.params[index]) IndexError: tuple index out of range
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sqlTest.py", line 40, in
>   
>       mycursor.execute(sql,val)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 558,
>   in execute
>       stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 86,
>   in **call**    "Not enough parameters for the SQL statement")
>   mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the
>   SQL statement

This is a section of my main project that would log the current values of certain Variable as well as the GPS Coordinates and a timestamp.

From what I've seen the main issue has to do with the database expecting 8 database entries when I should only need 7.

I mainly followed https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp tutorial as I am not super familiar with using python and mySQL together.

```
#Initialize mySQL databse connection
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="themySQLserver.net",
  user="myUSername",
  passwd="_____",
  database="24totheTLE"
)
```

These variables are normally set by the main program but I manually set them for troubleshooting

```
top_since_epoch = 4
left_since_epoch = 1
bottom_since_epoch = 5
right_since_epoch = 3
```

This is the code that calls the python2 script to get the gps data

```
fullgps = os.popen("python gps.py").read()
gps_split = fullgps.split(";")
gps_split[1] = gps_split[1].rstrip()
s1 = float(gps_split[0])
s2 = float(gps_split[1])
```

The primary key "LogNum" for my database is set to auto increment and as such I have not mentioned it in my code.

```
ts = time.time()
timestam = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO records (TimeStamp,CarsTop,CarsLeft,CarsRight,CarsBottom,GPSLong,GPSLat) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
val = [timestam,top_since_epoch,left_since_epoch,bottom_since_epoch,s2,s1]
mycursor.execute(sql,val)
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Thanks to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer

The problem was that the code I used to pass the date-time information was not set up to interact with the "mysql.connector" This was solved by updating the code to work with MySQLdb libaries:

This code Worked for me

```
#Initialize mySQL databse connection
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(
  host="sql24.cpt1.host-h.net",
  user="stonesp_1",
  passwd="______",
  database="24totheTLE"
)
print("5 minutes")
fullgps = os.popen("python gps.py").read()
gps_split = fullgps.split(";")

s1 = float(gps_split[0])
s2 = float(gps_split[1])
print(s1)
print(s2)
ts = time.time()
timecur = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(timecur)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO records (TimeStamp,CarsTop,CarsLeft,CarsRight,CarsBottom,GPSLong,GPSLat) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
val = [timecur,top_since_epoch,left_since_epoch,right_since_epoch,bottom_since_epoch,s2,s1]

mycursor.execute(sql,val)
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
mydb.close()
```